# Not able to access another EC2 instance from other instance via http custom port

Tags: amazon-ec2, load

I am trying to load test my application on Amazon EC2 M4 machines all on default vpc
Following is the configuration.

1. **Nginx server : m4.large machin**e. receives requests from jmeter which runs locally.
2. **Backend server: m4.xlarge**. The backend server is written in java.
3. **Simulator server: m4.large**: The backend server makes third party calls (e.g HTTP request SMS server hosted by Vodafone). For third party calls, simulators are written and deployed on this server.

The security group has all relevant ports enabled, specifically (no port range)
Also, the ulimits have been appropriately set and increased.

**Issue:** Initially the load tests run fine as per requirements. But after two days of runs, the HTTP calls to the simulator start timeout. This happens within 5 minutes of the new load test. And even when the Java application is restarted. The backend server is not able to ping the simulator server. However, the simulator server is accessible from other machines.

I see no such issue when I put the load on simulator server from my local JMeter

Are there any QoS limits getting applied on EC2 server. And how do I get around it?

Answer (score 0):

There are **no limits at the networking layer** that would throttle after a period of time/traffic.

The only enforced limits are **network bandwidth**, which is based upon the Instance Type. However, this is a constant bandwidth and will not change over time.

Instances from the T2 family also have usage credits that can be used to **burst CPU**, but this does not apply to your situation since you are using M4 instances.

Things to check:

- Make sure all instances are referring to each other via their **private IP address**, which means all traffic stays within the VPC
- Ping is disabled by default in Security Groups. If you wish it to function, then permit inbound ICMP traffic.

Also, a side-note: You should **create your own VPC** for your resources rather than using the Default VPC. This gives you full control over the VPC rather than relying on the default configuration. However, this will not impact bandwidth or throughput.

Comment: Thanks, John, I found this blog on the internet https://lab.getbase.com/how-we-discovered-limitations-on-the-aws-tcp-stack/  could this somehow be connected to issue I am facing? Being a newbie on AWS I am unable to co-relate. I will also try with own VPC and check.

Comment: Also, I have tried All TCP with 0.0.0.0/0 as stated in blog, but does not help